# AWS Java S3 Client read JSON file with double quotes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to read a JSON file stored in an AWS S3 bucket, but when I try to parse the result with GSON I get the following error, since the result is returned with double quotes: `"Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"`

Is there a way to read a JSON file from S3 without it coming with double quotes and the carriage return and newline special characters?

```java
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> event, Context context) {
        final var logger = context.getLogger();
        try (var provider = DefaultCredentialsProvider.create()) {
            logger.log("Credentials provided.");
            try (var s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                    .region(Region.US_EAST_2)
                    .credentialsProvider(provider)
                    .build()) {
                logger.log("S3 Client built.");

                final var request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                        .key("my-file.json")
                        .bucket("my-bucket")
                        .build();

                try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Client.getObject(request), UTF_8))) {
                    return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

JSON

```json
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "code": "abc",
      "name": "category-example",
      "movements": [
        {
          "name": "movement-example",
          "filenamePattern": "file-${year}-${month}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

LAMBDA RESPONSE

```
"{  \"categories\": [    {      \"code\": \"abc\",      \"name\": \"category-example\",      \"movements\": [        {          \"name\": \"movement-example\",          \"filenamePattern\": \"file-${year}-${month}\"        }      ]    }  ]}"
```

Comment: Please show us (at least some of) your file so we can understand what it contains.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi! I just update the question with the required file and response examples. Thanks.